# Rewrite of 2 custom modules

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks, overrides

I have 2 modules that rewrite the customer account navigation block:

```
<blocks>
    <customer>
         <rewrite>
              <account_navigation>ModuleA_Block_Navigation</account_navigation>
         </rewrite>
    </customer>
</blocks>
```

and

```
<blocks>
  <moduleB>
      <class>ModuleB_Block</class>
  </moduleB>
   <customer>
     <rewrite>
      <account_navigation>ModuleB_Block_Customer_Account_Navigation</account_navigation>
     </rewrite>
   </customer>
</blocks>
```

And I need to make ModuleA dependent on ModuleB. But I don't really get the logic of the `rewrite` configuration in this case...

Both classes extend the core class:

```
class ModuleA_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation
```

and

```
class ModuleB_Block_Customer_Account_Navigation extends Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation
```

and each has one function, which is with the same name: `removeLink()` but in ModuleA it is without arguments, and in ModuleB it has 1 argument: `removeLink($var)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make ModuleA dependent on ModuleB.
In app/etc/modules initialization file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Namespace_ModuleA>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Namespace_ModuleB/>
        </depends>
    </Namespace_ModuleA>
</modules>
</config>
```

ModuleB class ModuleB_Block_Customer_Account_Navigation extend from magento's one, but do not use rewrites.
ModuleA class ModuleA_Block_Customer_Account_Navigation extend from ModuleB_Block_Customer_Account_Navigation. And in  ModileA module's config xml rewrite:

```
<blocks>
<customer>
     <rewrite>
              <account_navigation>ModuleA_Block_Customer_Account_Navigation</account_navigation>
     </rewrite>
</customer>
</blocks>
```

This should help.

Comment: That seems reasonable. But now none of the modules works.

Comment: Are there some errors?

Comment: Yeah, I checked the exception.log and there was incompatibility between functions in the 2 Block classes. Thanks for that. :)